Algolia search function returns only first 20 results
I have this Python function to return all verified venues using algolia
def get_all_venues():
    try:
        page = 0
        hits_per_page = 1000  # Increase this value
        while True:
            result = index.search("", {
                "filters": "is_verified=1",
                "page": page,
                "hitsPerPage": hits_per_page
            })
            hits = result["hits"]
            if not hits:
                break  # Break the loop if there are no more hits
            with open("venues.csv", "a") as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                for hit in hits:
                    venue_id = hit["venue_id"]
                    venue_name = hit["venue_name"]
                    is_verified = hit["is_verified"]
                    fields = [venue_id, venue_name, is_verified]
                    writer.writerow(fields)
                    print(str(venue_id) + ": " + str(venue_name))
            page += 1  # Move to the next page

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))

get_all_venues()

When I run it, it returns only the first 20 results. I know there are at least 20000 results in the dataset. I know this because I have tried an alternative method.
What I have tried
I wrote a function which takes a venue_id and manually checks if the is_verified value is equal to 1 and if it is, then it writes to the csv. However, this is very tedious as I have to set a range of venue_id values in the millions and check every single record which makes the script take days. I am certain the filter is faster, so I want to use the filter instead.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rHbH7pRAkIYg_NSJSODO7-hAHOZLHfjy/view?usp=sharing couldnt replicate. have you added is_verified in attributesForFaceting.  i tried with records look like { "objectID": 1, "venue_id": "12345", "venue_name": "Example Venue 1", "is_verified": 1 }. total 45 recs, is_verified=1-35 recs

i also think browse would be the best for your usecase
